# What is the real physical property behind the term "temperature" on macro-level?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, thermal-conductivity

Let's assume I have two ideal cubic solid bodies. I place them close to each other, so there is no gap between faces. For simplicity let it be in vacuum. And they will start to interact by exchanging energy in form of heat.

From macro point of view the heat can be expressed as some kind of internal body energy, and somehow the more energetic object ("warm") tends to give some of it's energy to the less energetic one ("cool").

The measure of the object's energy per mass is a **thermal capacity**. And the speed of spreading the energy per length/square/volume is a **thermal conductivity**. So objects can store more, but collect it slowly. Or store less, but collect it fast.

But somehow some unknown physical property comes into all the formulas: the temperature. What is it?

Is it just some mathematical trick to simplify formulas to represent the thermal equilibrium?

Comment: I wouldn't call it just some mathematical trick; but simplifying models on the macroscopic scale definitely isn't unique to temperature.  Just think about how we treat objects in classical mechanics compared to quantum mechanics.  At a large enough scale, if you aren't concerned about the very small details, you can simplify things.  I don't know enough about modern thermodynamics to give a very satisfying answer; just this general anecdote that we definitely like to simply large systems when appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

For any large collection of (identical) gas molecules, the energies of those molecules will depend on how fast they are bouncing around. Those velocities, in turn, exist in a distribution of values- some are moving fast, some are moving slow, and some are in between. This means that the individual energies of those molecules will exist in a distribution too.

If we then allow a container of these gas molecules to sit for a while, the molecules will share energy back and forth amongst themselves as they bounce off each other; in this process, the most energetic of them will share some energy with the least energetic and after a while the net amount of energy entering any little parcel of gas in the container will equal the amount leaving it. We then say that the gas has achieved *thermal equilibrium* and the corresponding energy distribution takes on a special, unique shape with a hump in the middle and ends that trail off to the high and low ends of the energy spectrum.

We then define the *temperature* of that container of gas to correspond to the most likely energy that any molecule in the container can have, which is equal to that at the peak of the distribution. In this way the temperature- a macroscopic attribute of a very large collection of molecules- tells us something useful about the microscopic behavior of the individual molecules in that collection.

Comment: That's a good description! But only for gases - and in case of gas the temperature is still just mean value for energy of some body "parts", and seems redundant - in case of internal equilibrium we can describe behavior of molecules just knowing the total heat energy of the body. Also it doesn't describe the solid objects too well, and still doesn't explain the property of any abstract object (gas, liquid, solid and other intermediate states) as a whole.

Answer (score -1):

Heat at the micro scale would refer to the vibrational energy possessed by the individual atoms. The more the atom vibrates the higher is its energy.

Temperature is a physical quantity like length and mass which we use to quantify this heat. It is one of the seven fundamental units and has been defined as an SI unit. Energy of a body may be converted to kinetic energy or potential energy or be used to increase the temperature of the body. Temperature can be thought of as another inherent physical property of a body.

The above explanation is in context of classical mechanics. Hence this explanation wont work at the smallest of scales and one would have to turn to quantum mechanics.
Hope this helps!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. It just says temperature is a quantity used to describe objects which is somehow related to heat, all of which was essentially discussed in the question.